# Resgatar período de tempo no r

Tags: r, data

Olá, tenho uma série grande de dados temporais. Tenho mais de 100 anos pra trabalhar. Eu preciso resgatar (abstrair) apenas os verões de cada um dos anos, e não sei como fazer no R. Por exemplo, preciso do período de tempo 20/06/2015 a 20/09/2015, e dos anos anteriores como 2014,2013, que estão contidos todos juntos na mesma série.
Alguém pode me ajudar com uma fórmula ou comando?

Comment: do que você precisa nesse período ? dias, semanas, horas, ... ?

Comment: estou trabalhando com dados climáticos, preciso resgatar a data e a temperatura média deste período.

Comment: talvez esse dois links possam lhe ajudar: https://biologyforfun.wordpress.com/2014/05/05/importing-100-years-of-climate-change-into-r/    e   https://ropensci.org/blog/2013/08/18/sciordata/

Comment: Obrigada, vou dar uma olhada.

Answer (score 1):

Não vi como os seus dados estão estrturados então inventei um banco de dados.
Essa sequência de operações vai pegar apenas o período de 20/06 a 20/09 de todos os anos que estão na base.

```
library(lubridate)
library(dplyr)

dados <- data.frame(
  datas = seq(as.Date('1900-01-01'),as.Date('2000-12-31'),by = 1),
  valor = 1:36890
)

dados %>% tbl_df %>%
  # pegar apenas os meses de junho a setembro
  filter(month(datas) <= 9, month(datas) >= 6) %>%
  # se for junho, só pegar os dias maiores que 20
  filter(!(month(datas) == 6 & day(datas) < 20)) %>%
  # se for setembro pegar os dias menores do que 20
  filter(!(month(datas) == 9 & day(datas) > 20))

Source: local data frame [9,393 x 2]

        datas valor
       (date) (int)
1  1900-06-20   171
2  1900-06-21   172
3  1900-06-22   173
4  1900-06-23   174
5  1900-06-24   175
6  1900-06-25   176
7  1900-06-26   177
8  1900-06-27   178
9  1900-06-28   179
10 1900-06-29   180
..        ...   ...
```

Comment: Olá, os dados são parecidos mesmo. Vou testar e aviso se deu certo. Obrigada.

Comment: Gostaria de entender este comando:  dados %>% tbl_df %>%

Comment: Esta dando este erro na minha programação. Error in data.frame(datas = seq(as.Date("01-01-1979"), as.Date("28-10-2014"),  : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 10137, 13080

Comment: Isso seria colunas e linhas respectivamente?  (valor = 1:36890)

Comment: Este passo cria uma base de dados só p/ você testar o código a seguir. Por isso crio uma base simples, com duas colunas: `datas` e `valor`.
Nesse código que você postou, tem dois problemas: as datas estão escritas no formato brasileiro, mas esse comando só entende o formato americano `aaaa-mm-dd`. Mas o erro está acontecendo pq o seu vetor de valores é maior do que o vetor de datas que você cria. No meu exemplo quando coloquei `1:36890` era pq de 1900 a 2000 passaram-se 36890 dias .